# Не платите за ошибки (?) платите за качество вашей системы

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Какой вариант написания верный:

1. Не платите за ошибки, платите за качество вашей системы.
2. Не платите за ошибки — платите за качество вашей системы.

Comment: О какой «вашей системе» идёт речь? О каких ошибках?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае это бессоюзное сложное предложение. Первая часть противопоставляется второй(можно поставить союз "а").
Согласно Розенталю:
2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз но или а): Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно (Гр.); Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил (Гр.); Шить сядет — не умеет взять иголку; её бранят — она себе молчит (П.); Прошла неделя, месяц — он к себе домой не возвращался (П.); Я хвать за пояс — пистолета нет (Л.);